# Как сделать выборку за последнюю секунду?

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

Я хочу сделать такой запрос:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM loan WHERE country = 'lv' AND created_at > current_timestamp - second(1)
```

Как мне заменить `second(1)` на валидное выражение, чтобы отрабатывало в `h2` и `postgres` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разных реализациях SQL к сожалению никакого порядка с обработкой дат и времени. Попробуйте, умеет ли ваша `h2` интервалы времени:

```
select now() - interval '1 second'
```

Если не умеет, то можно научить `postgresql` имитировать поведение `h2` создав функцию такого вида:

```
create function second(int) 
returns interval 
immutable strict language sql as $$ 
    select interval '1 second' * $1 
$$;
```

И приведённый в вопросе запрос будет работать корректно.

---

Небольшое недопонимание, нужен запрос и для `h2` тоже. Судя по [документации `h2`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) подходит функция `dateadd`, т.е. возможно соорудить запрос вот так:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM loan 
WHERE country = 'lv' 
    AND created_at > DATEADD('SECOND', -1, current_timestamp)
```

`PostgreSQL` такую функцию не знает, но можно создать пользовательскую и выполнять такую же логику.

```
create function dateadd(text, int, timestamp) 
returns timestamp 
immutable strict language sql as $$ 
    select $3 + concat($2, ' ', $1)::interval 
$$;
```

Для размерности `second` точно работает, и будет работать для других размерностей времени для которых `h2` и `postgresql` используют одинаковые наименования - например для `month`. Если наименование периода времени `postgresql` не знает то будет ошибка.

Comment: Мой `sql` был больше псевдокодом... В `h2`, к сожалению, нельзя сделать `second(1)`. Т.е. я вообще не знаю как это сделать в `h2`.

Comment: Печально, а я подумал что это известный запрос для h2. Нужен кто-то кто знаком с h2, а я могу только сказать как такое сделать в pg либо как имитировать поведение.

Comment: Попробуйте в h2 `created_at > DATEADD('SECOND', -1, current_timestamp)` http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd Если так умеет, то напишу функцию для postgresql

Comment: Это сработало :)